# Which user-agent should I use?

Tags: java, search-engine, web-crawler

I have build a webcrawler that should crawl my customers site every night. I do not want my requests to show up in their Google analytics, so how do I insure this automatically?

As far as I know, it is via the user-agent that I indicate that the request is comming from a crawler. So which user-agent string should I use to get analytics filtering out my requests by default(so that the customer do not need to filter the request out of their reports)

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics is a client side tool. So if your crawl action is server side as common, whatever you set for user-agent it already can not report about your requests.